# Lookup records not diplay in Experience Cloud for Guest Profile

Tags: lookup, experience-cloud, digital-experience, lookup-field

I have Screenflow with Lookup components and i setup experince cloud with guest access.
I gave all permissions but i can't see the Lookup records in Experience cloud site as guest user.
Please help on this??

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to include more detail about your specific issue, including the objects involved, what sharing settings and rules you have enabled on the Guest user, etc.

Answer (score 0):

1.Does the guestuser have access to the object?

2.Did you review the sharing rules and org-wide default of the object? Do
check that.

For a Guestuser to be able to see records , he needs a sharing rule that share the records with him . did you create a sharing rule for the guest user ?
if you didn't, you can check the [link](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_sharing_rules_guest.htm&type=5) to create sharing rules for Guestuser.

Comment: Yes, Guest User have all the necessory permissions, but i can not see records in lookup fileds.